# Подыматься или подниматься?

Tags: синонимы, глаголы, просторечия

Текст следующий:

> Теперь марсоходу предстоит спуск по долине. Её длина эквивалентна двум
>   футбольным полям, крутизна склона составляет 15-17 градусов. Процесс
>   спуска может занять немало времени. Ведь если на пути аппарата
>   встретится препятствие, то для его объезда ему придется снова
>   **подыматься** наверх. ([Источник](http://kiri2ll.livejournal.com/713309.html))

Слово *подыматься* резануло слух, пошёл разбираться. В словарях указано, что это просторечный эквивалент слова *подниматься*.

Помогите разобраться.

Comment: Длина эквивалентна полю? Если оставлять «эквивалентна», то по отношению к площади, не вырывая из неё деталь (длину), правильнее говорить о долине, эквивалентной двум полям, но с крутизной в 15 град.

Answer (score 5):

Существуют два глагола:  **поднять/поднимать и подъять/подымать.**

В современном языке второй глагол используется преимущественно в **разговорном** стиле, а также может иметь пометку "**книжн. устар**".

Однако до недавнего времени  он использовался в обычной речи без стилевых ограничений.

**Примеры:**

Завтра **подыму** вас рано.

А мне еще Пашку **подымать** надо! А на что, спрашивается? [Александр Мишарин. Белый, белый день // «Октябрь», 2003]

Тем с большей настойчивостью мы должны **подымать** миллионные массы рабочих и крестьян на дело критики снизу, [И. В. Сталин 1928]

Comment: До какого "недавнего времени"?

Пашка-то почему "без стилевых ограничений"? Самое что ни на есть разговорное. Да и "подыму вас рано" тоже.

Comment: Действительно, в предложении "А мне еще Пашку подымать надо!" - глагол "подымать" используется в речи героя.

Comment: Ну да, это разговорный стиль, характеризующий речь персонажа. Обычный литературный прием, сам писатель, скорее всего, пользуется словом "поднимать".

Answer (score 0):

Да, "подымать" — просторечный эквивалент слова "поднимать". "Подниматься наверх" содержит избыточность (плеоназм), достаточно просто сказать "подниматься". Вся заметка — не очень грамотный пересказ английского оригинала. Например, "The valley extends down ... for a distance of about two football fields" следовало бы перевести примерно так: "Долина простирается вниз на расстояние, примерно равное длине двух футбольных полей". А в преводе на русский, как заметил @shampar, длина сравнивается с площадью(?!). Переводчик не понял разницу межды склоном и уклоном (Склоны долины — это то, что ограничивает ее с боков, а уклон долины — крутизна ее дна), Не крутизна склона, а уклон составляет 15–17 градусов.